# How do I change the user home folder name?

Tags: permissions

I have a buyer for my desktop PC with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.  I need to change the home folder name from `robert` to `james`.  I've managed the other tasks like hostname, user name, user password.   After attempting to change the home folder name:  grub/recovery/root shell:

```
mount -o remount,rw / 
usermod -d /home/james -m robert
reboot
```

I can't get past the greeting screen login.  When I enter James' password, the screen blanks briefly then opens again at that same login screen.

Comment: Why renaming the user account? Are there any important settings or data files you really want to sell together with the computer hardware? If not, just delete the old user account after creating a new admin user. Or even better (I personally would never give any data storage away before that!) overwrite the entire disk with a special data shredding tool (like "Darik's Boot And Nuke" / DBAN) and reinstall a clean system to make sure the purchaser can't recover any sensitive data.

Comment: I set the robert desktop up with Docky and Mac themes, minimizing the unity panel.   The buyer likes it that way also.  Oh, I used BootitNG to wipe the HD.   Not worried about what might be left on the HD.   Came from an auction.

Comment: Ok, so I added James in system settings/user accounts, account type administrator, and a unique password.   At Greeting screen I can choose from robert or james.   But, I want the james desktop to look exactly like the robert desktop.   Can that be done ?

Comment: You should ask that in a comment below @Rinzwind's answer. I think he can help you better with that. However, I think simply setting that desktop configuration for the new user again could probably be faster, easier and more stable than figuring out what to copy...

Comment: Yep,  I re-worked the desktop for James like it was with Robert.   Took about 20 min. to do that.   No actual solution to my question, but I'm going with this now.   Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it like this:

1. create user "james";
2. switch sudo account to "james";
3. move over personal files to "james". "chown"/"chgrp" them to "james";
4. check you can log into "james". If not and login is shown, check `~/xsession-errors` for notices.
5. remove "robert".

> When I enter James' password, the screen blanks briefly then opens again at that same login screen.

The answer to this problem is probably shown in `~/xsession.errors`. You can also just remove `~./Xauthority`. That one needs specific permissions for login to success (has to be `rw- --- ---` and owned and group set to the user.)

Comment: As the computer is to be sold, I don't really think that there would be any personal data that should stay on it. I personally would rather run a boot-and-nuke to securely overwrite the entire disk and then reinstall a fresh system before selling it. You know, simply deleted files can often easily be recovered and there's usually more data remaining on a system than you know of. For example one could see what pictures you had on your computer by looking at the thumbnail cache, and that's just one example. Just because you are not paranoid does not mean that they won't come for you. ;-D